# SVG marker disappears when SVG with identical definition is hidden

Tags: html, svg, browser, rendering

Consider [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fefrei/gy68p3em/7/) HTML fragment:

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg class="graph" style="visibility: hidden">
        <style type="text/css">
            <![CDATA[
              .arrow {
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke: #000;
                marker-end: url(#arrowhead);
              }
            ]]>
        </style>
        <defs>
            <marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="10" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path fill="#000" d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z"></path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <path class="arrow" d="M 0 0 L 100 10"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg class="graph">
        <style type="text/css">
            <![CDATA[
              .arrow {
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke: #000;
                marker-end: url(#arrowhead);
              }
            ]]>
        </style>
        <defs>
            <marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="10" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path fill="#000" d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z"></path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <path class="arrow" d="M 0 0 L 100 10"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

It contains an SVG element that shows a short arrow with an arrowhead, defined within the `<defs>` section of the SVG element. More specifically, it contains two copies of that image.

This would usually render like this:

[image: two arrows]

However, the first SVG element is hidden. In Chrome, the result looks like this:

[image: one line with no arrow head]

It looks like the marker definition is invalidated by the first SVG being hidden – but there is a redundant definition in the second SVG (and by scoping, each definition should only apply to its own element).

In Firefox, I'm seeing identical rendering. Safari shows the arrow head.

Why are Chrome and Firefox not rendering the arrow head?
Is this a bug in both browsers, or am I misunderstanding the specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main error: you are using the same `id`s twice. Also I would change the `refX="10"` for the `arrowhead` to something else, like 5.

If you need to use the arrow again, do it with an `<use>` element.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:45vw;}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
    <svg class="graph" viewBox="-10 -10 120 50">
        <style type="text/css">
            <![CDATA[
              .arrow {
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke: #000;
                marker-end: url(#arrowhead);
              }
            ]]>
        </style>
        <defs>
            <marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="10" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path fill="#000" d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z"></path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <path class="arrow" id="theArrow" d="M 0 0 L 100 10"></path>
    </svg>
    
 <svg class="graph" viewBox="-10 -10 120 50">
 <use xlink:href="#theArrow" />
 </svg>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: OK, so this boils down to: Multiple SVGs within the same HTML document *do* share the same namespace for `id`s, contrary to what I believed. Thanks!